# Is there any way to use not public android resources in my application?

Tags: android, resources

I need to use the following resources in my widget:

- pressed_application_background_static
- focused_application_background_static

I hope that usage of these resources will allow me to have orange background on standard android and green on HTC.

But they are not public, so usage of

```
android:drawable="@android:drawable/pressed_application_background_static"
```

is not allowed. Is still there any way to use them?

Answer (score 55):

You can reference them like this

```
android:drawable="@*android:drawable/pressed_application_background_static"
```

but it is not recommended, because private resources are likely to be renamed or removed in the future.

Comment: It allows you to access private resources. I guess it's there to warn you. You can use @android:drawable without worries, but when using @*android:drawable you should be aware that it's not guaranteed to be there, so you're doing it at your own risk.

Comment: When doing this with latest SDK I get the error message "Illegal resource reference: @*android resources are private and not always present"

Comment: @Jules If your using IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio you can do ALT + Enter and suppress the warning for that file.

Answer (score 4):

browse the sdk for the drawable and copy it locally to you res/drawable folder.  it will probably be an XML file but if you search for "pressed_application_background_static" you should find it without trouble.

Comment: this is what I've already done - but this is not what I am looking for. With such approach colour will be always the same, on all devices. But I need to have it green on HTC and orange on standard Android. That is why I want to refer to standard resources.

Comment: How do you distinguish between an HTC Android and a plain Android?

Comment: I don't know to distinguish between them, so I expect that if I use standard resources (`@android:drawable/`), then different resources will be used on HTC and plain Android.

Comment: that file will be different on a plain Android device compared to an HTC device if one shows green and the other orange.  and if you can't access it because it is 'private', my only suggestion is to figure out how to distinguish between OS's and change the drawable used.