# Getting error message "Resource is not public"

Tags: android, android-layout

So I'm trying to use the built-in drawable timepicker_up_btn for api level 7.  It is in the actual res folder in the sdk, and I can use other resources from that folder.  But I get the error message "Resource is not public".

It seems like Google is trying to limit the use of this resource.  I would think they don't care if I use it in an Android application and it makes the overall look of my application similar to stock Android.

Anyway, is this fixable?  Can I somehow use a non-public resource without copying it to my project?  And what is the deal with copying stock resources to own projects?  Illegal?  Frowned upon?  Or go ahead we don't care?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The best thing to do is to copy the files to our application. I was told by some Google employees that you should not reference the resources, rather copy them to your application.

One of the reasons for this is that if you reference a whole bunch of icons for your application, you are not guaranteed that every one of these is updated at the same time when new versions of the SDK is released. You might end up with some up-to-date fancy icons and some old ones :)

Comment: As to the continuum from one api level to the next they already changes so much that even code like android:layout_width could be something else - even thought that example is unlikely to change.

Comment: Exactly, so copy the files you need :)

Comment: Edit to above as I clicked Enter by mistake and cannot edit it after 5 minutes, so add this to my comment above:  For example the timepicker_ is changed to numberpicker_ in latest apis.  So keeping track when using adroid: stuff is needed anyhow.  It seems like I will have to copy these resources to my project, but it would be so much easier if I could just reference the stock resources - and it would feel more correct.

Comment: I would also like to know if there is a reason as to why the resource timepicker_up_btn is non-public and the resource toast_frame is public?  Would be fun to know why and how.

Comment: I totally agree with you, it feels more correct to reference it. I'm not sure why some resources are not public but I will post a comment if I find out.

Comment: But would the attributes be different in different devices? I prefer to use the * annotation instead, as I am afraid of the difference

Answer (score 8):

[Is there any way to use not public android resources in my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685456/is-there-any-way-to-use-not-public-android-resources-in-my-application])

You can reference them like this

**android:drawable="@*android:drawable/pressed_application_background_static"**

but it is not recommended, because private resources are likely to be renamed or removed in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can copy the resource from SDK folder to your own resource folder and then use it as your own. Though I am not sure whether it's a violation of the copyright.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward. Google maintains the copyright of course, but, licenses all of Android to you under the terms of the Apache License 2.0. You can use it, just be aware of the license terms. Essentially the user has to know they've received such licensed software from Google. I'd argue on Android they've already done so!