# How to give animation to the ViewSwitcher

Tags: android, android-animation

I have created one advertisement control which consists of ViewSwitcher....

in that control i have ImageView and TextView because advertisement are of either text or images..

Now i have to give animation to the advetisements..

I have tried following

> Animation inAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
>       inAnimation.setDuration(1500);
>
> Animation outAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
>   android.R.anim.slide_out_right);      outAnimation.setDuration(1500);

And i set it to the switcher as

> ViewSwitcher switcher;
>
> switcher.setInAnimation(inAnimation);
>
> switcher.setOutAnimation(outAnimation);

but it won't work..

Please give me any other alternative.. Or if use of above code is wrong then how to use it??

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try setting animation inside xml as

```
<ViewSwitcher
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
    android:outAnimation="@android:anim/slide_out_right" >
```

Comment: is there any way to give vertical animation like in from upper side and out from lower side like this??

Comment: @Rashmi: You can use `"@android:anim/slide_in_up"` and `"@android:anim/slide_out_down"`. If you get the error message "Resource is not public", check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8019405/1097104.

Comment: If you wish to rotate it - just use `android:rotation` nest your content one more layout lower and use `android:rotation` in the opposite direction

Answer (score 9):

In addition to this :

Take care of switcher.showNext(); or switcher.showPrevious();

If you set an animation to the switcher, both action will result in the **same** animation.

Answer (score 3):

I am giving an alternative as mentioned in the question. Using this you will achieve the same animation that ViewPager have.

Instead of showNext, you can set displayedChild to 1.

```
switcherView?.inAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(baseActivity, R.anim.slide_in_right)
switcherView?.outAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(baseActivity, R.anim.slide_out_left)
switcherView?.displayedChild = 1
```

Instead of showPrevious, you can set displayedChild to 0.

```
switcherView?.inAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(baseActivity, R.anim.slide_in_left)
switcherView?.outAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(baseActivity, R.anim.slide_out_right)
switcherView?.displayedChild = 0
```

Animation Files:
R.anim.slide_in_right:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

R.anim.slide_out_left

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" />
</set>
```

R.anim.slide_in_left

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

R.anim.slide_out_right

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

Each time you set displayedChild, you need to set the animation. If you don't want the animation, you can simply neglect it.That's all. Happy Coding!

PS: Kotlin code

Answer (score 2):

Nothing happen or you got some error? What u mean by it won't work?

Did you start animation with `switcher.showNext();` or `switcher.showPrevious();`

Hope it will help.. Cheers ;)

Comment: i have used the switcher.showNext() method.. but it wont slide in and slide out as mentioned...

Answer (score 0):

A "switcher.showNext();" from the last layout and a "switcher.showPrevious();" from the first layout gives error. It must be similar to the stackoverflow and stackunderflow situation in a stack.so before you call "showNext()" check its not the last layout that you are currently in and also that you are not in the first layout when calling  "showPrevious()". I came across this simple mistake.
Sorry for making this a post, I am (a rookie) not yet authorised to comment on posts