# Holo.Light gives "Resource not public" error

Tags: android, intellij-idea

IN the following code sample, I am trying to set the default theme of my application to the light holo style:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Holo.Light">
```

However, it gives an error stating "Resource not public". I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018954/getting-error-message-resource-is-not-public) similar question, and the advice is to copy the theme into your application. However, I was under the impression that since 4.0 this was unnecessary as for certification a device must include a copy of the unmodified theme.

Can anyone advise as to the cause of the error and a possible solution? If relevant, my ide is the latest IntelliJ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Theme.Holo.Light` instead of `Holo.Light`.