# I am getting a lot of Errors in my Timer App. Most of them seem to be because the resource is private

Tags: java, android

So I have been getting this error while trying to run the app. I am very new to the whole android thing, this is out of my course and I was trying to try something new to my app, but I understand the resources I have used in button and Seekbar is Private and cant be used publicly, I am sure there has to be a fix, Can anyone explain me this, please?

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
    C:\Users\nefar\AndroidStudioProjects\eggtimer\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
    Error:error: resource android:attr/lightRadius is private.
    Error:resource android:attr/lightRadius is private.
    Error:failed linking file resources.
    Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Failed to execute aapt
>       Information:BUILD FAILED in 8s
>       Information:7 errors
>       Information:0 warnings
>       Information:See complete output in console

```
#Layout#

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    tools:context="com.example.android.eggtimer.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="go.!"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:scrollbarSize="?android:attr/lightRadius"
        android:thumbTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:text="00:30"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>




##Java##

package com.example.android.eggtimer;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        final TextView timerTextView = findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);
        seekBar.setMax(600);
        seekBar.setProgress(30);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                int minutes = progress/ 60;
                int seconds = progress - minutes * 60;
                timerTextView.setText(Integer.toString(minutes) + ":" + Integer.toString(seconds));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error: `Error:resource android:attr/lightRadius is private.`
You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42310457/1080355) to help, but as it suggested, `private` properties may be removed from android mainstream without notice and cause your application stop working in future releases of Android. So you can follow what suggested on that answer, and in your case you can simply add your `lightRadius` to your theme attributes or add it as a value to your resources inside a file like `values.xml` or even you can hardcode the value with something like below (which is not suggested but helps to fix error):

```
android:scrollbarSize="600dp"
```

The value `600dp` is brought from `platforms\android-22\data\res\values` inisde API 22 resources inside android SDK folder:

**attrs.xml**

```
<attr name="lightRadius" format="dimension" />
```

**themes.xml**

```
<item name="lightRadius">@dimen/light_radius</item>
```

**dimens.xml**

```
 <dimen name="light_radius">600dp</dimen>
```

Comment: I tried doing as you said, I get an error that says Element must be declared. I am sorry as this must be a very Basic fix, but since I am a noob, I have no idea of how to fix that.