# Why cant Android Studio find certain resources

Tags: android

[image]I'm trying to use the Android drawable `ic_menu_start_conversation` in my app, yet Android Studio says it can't find it, and aant crashes if I try to build my app. However, if I look in `External Librarys > Android API 19 Platform > res > drawable` the png is there, and the preview can find it.

Do I need to just make a local copy of this to be able to use it?

Same issues applies for `ic_menu_compose` and a few others

Comment: Android Studious is still under development and shows strange behavior some times. I also frustrated due to issues and moved back to eclipse. Try by restarting IDE.

Comment: As google said. Caution: Android Studio is currently available as an early access preview. Several features are either incomplete or not yet implemented and you may encounter bugs. If you are not comfortable using an unfinished product, you may want to instead download (or continue to use) the ADT Bundle (Eclipse with the ADT Plugin).

Comment: I've not had too many issues with it, but I am thinking of maybe moving to Intellij until it's a little more developed.

Comment: Can you put the text of your layout XML file in your question? I can't make it out from the screenshot.

Comment: I can't the the file till monday, but this is the link to the full size image http://i.stack.imgur.com/JY6gd.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I try to reproduce your problem, I get this error when building (it's buried in a larger error message from AAPT):

```
Error: Resource is not public. (at 'icon' with value '@android:drawable/ic_menu_start_conversation').
```

You can find more information on that here:

[Is there any way to use not public android resources in my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685456/is-there-any-way-to-use-not-public-android-resources-in-my-application)

When I tried to override it and use the resource anyway via:

```
android:icon="@*android:drawable/ic_menu_start_conversation"
```

It was able to build the project, though the IDE still showed it as an error (angry red underline in the XML) because you're not supposed to use private resources. When I tried running the app in an API 19 emulator, the icon didn't show up. I was quite possibly doing something wrong (though I did make sure my min/target API versions were 19 and my build tools version was 19.0.X), but that points to the fact that using private resources is fragile, and you're better off copying the resource unless you have a really specific reason for not doing so.

Comment: I've had just copied it over now, I didn't know about that `@*` override thing, that might come in useful for other debugging thing :)