# Can't use android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.Switch

Tags: android, android-styles, togglebutton

I have this error : Error:(15) error: resource android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.Switch is private.

And I really want to use this style. How can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Visit <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685456/is-there-any-way-to-use-not-public-android-resources-in-my-application>